# Error: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Getting annoying build errors since upgrading to VS2017 (v15.18.6) and dot net core 2.1.
I previously was able to build the .sln from https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet.

I'm new to the whole .net standard/core stuff (frankly find MS approach to this rather confusing and annoying!).
Anyway since the upgrade to the new VS2017 build and 2.1, I get the following 2 errors:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.0.  Either target .NET Standard 1.6 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.0. MiniProfiler.Shared C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   126
>
> Error  NETSDK1050  The version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk used by this project is insufficient to support references to libraries targeting .NET Standard 1.5 or higher.  Please install version 2.0 or higher of the .NET Core SDK. MiniProfiler.Shared C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets  67

[image]

Any ideas ?
I have searched online and seem various similar issues but I don't really understand the underlying issue.

Comment: @mikez I thought too so but then I have had 4.6.1 for a while.

Comment: Yes I see you say it stopped working after upgrading to 15.8.6 which makes me think its a bug. I've had many coworkers complain about recent updates breaking things so I'm not surprised.

Comment: @mikez Just as you typed,  I reverted back to VS2017 15.7.6 and it all seems to build OK. Maybe something related to the MSBuild sdk that was updated? Not sure but what a mess from MS in how they are managing .NET with VS. It's been a while since I had build issues from upgrading to VS versions even major upgrades.

Comment: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/StackExchange/dotnet/branch/master The code itself uses SDK 2.1.300 to build on AppVeyor, so I guess you should do the same.

Comment: @LexLi that's interesting, I already have 2.1.403 so I would have thought this would be inclusive of 300. Any ideas how I force it to build using a specific version anyway?

Comment: You seem to know little about `global.json`, https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/global.json The specific SDK is needed unless you modify the version in this file, or simply remove this file.

Comment: @LexLi I have heard of it but no expert with the .net core/standards as I normally stick to .net frameworks but noticed the global.json it wasn't referenced in the sln file so assumed it wasn't used by VS. You haven't answered my actual question though? why does VS older builds work and isn't 300 of 403 under semantic versioning?

Comment: @LexLi I have read that same article and don't get so uppity and rude. The article seems related dotnet commands rather than using VS so why don't you stop pasting urls without checking actual context. The point of stackflow is to ask and get an answer to questions. If you don't have anything relevant to answer then move on. You have yet to explain why it doesn't work on the latest version which was kind of the point?

Comment: "The specific SDK is needed unless you modify the version in this file, or simply remove this file." Microsoft intentionally designed it that way so you should never assume "the latest" should work. All I pointed out above serves as evidence. I left comments, not answer, and I am intentional too.

Comment: I got your evidence but I wanted to understand why one VS version didn't care about the global.json and another cared when usage had been around a while. I was curious about this why it changed between two patch builds of VS. Wanted to under the cause rather. Your initial answers were rather patronising and works against the point of stackoverflow of cultivating discussion and answers/explanations. We can all google but often need a little hand putting together a solution and that should never be discouraged on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you're using core and not targeting it. and it seems somehow you've brought standard and core into your app and thats causing a conflict. go through youre dependencies and references and make sure all the .NET options are set to the same either core or standard. then once youve chosen youre version, make sure to set the target to match it. standard is slightly more powerful at the moment, but its about to be depricated, so if you can switch to core and still have the functionality you need i reccomend doing do as this will increase the longevity of your project. plus linux and mac options.

Comment: Could you provide more info? The code is directly from github. Where do I set the target version and to what ? All I'm doing is trying to build something that previously built using presumably a .netstandard / framework that was on my machine